# Cannot get a numeric value from a text cell while getting data from xlsx file

Tags: java, apache-poi

Getting below error while reading data from a `.xlsx` file. I am not able to read data due to this error. Facing the error message "cannot get a numeric value from a text cell".

Here is the code:

```
switch (cell.getCellType()) {
    case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
        rowArray[count] = isCellDateFormatted(cell) ? dateFormat.format(cell.getDateCellValue()) : Double.toString(cell.getNumericCellValue());
        break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
        rowArray[count] = Boolean.toString(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
        break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
        rowArray[count] = isCellDateFormatted(cell) ? dateFormat.format(cell.getDateCellValue()) : Double.toString(cell.getNumericCellValue());
        break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
        rowArray[count] = cell.getStringCellValue().replace(separatorStr, escapeStr + separatorStr).replace("\n", " ");
        break;
    default:
        rowArray[count] = "";
}
```

Here is the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a numeric value from a text cell
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.typeMismatch(XSSFCell.java:994)
 at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getNumericCellValue(XSSFCell.java:305)
 at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(DateUtil.java:494)
 at cvx.qwer.adfffg.excel.XlsxToCsv.convertToCsv(XlsxToCsv.java:76)
 at cvx.qwer.adfffg.excel.XlsxToCsv.main(XlsxToCsv.java:136)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please format the question to make the code readable

Comment: I formatted the question. please check now.

Comment: Seems like the cell having the date is not date type cell. Try changing the cell type to date in excel file.

Comment: Formulas can return strings as results, they are not only numeric cells!

Comment: Can I use HSSFRichTextString to get the numericvalue from the formula

Comment: case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                            try {
                                rowArray[count] = isCellDateFormatted(cell) ? dateFormat.format(cell.getDateCellValue()):  HSSFRichTextString richString = cell.getRichStringCellValue());
                                rowArray[count] = stringValue.getString();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                //System.out.println("Numeric formula");
                                rowArray[count] = cell.getNumericCellValue()+"";
                            }

Answer (score 1):

As of your showed code the `rowArray` seems to be a `String` array. So the need is to get all cell values as `String` representations. Best way to do so is using [DataFormatter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) in combination with [FormulaEvaluator](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html):

```
...
Workbook workbook ...
...
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
...
Cell cell ...
...
rowArray[count] = formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator);
...
```

Using this the whole switching the cell types is not necessary. 
[DataFormatter.formatCellValue](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html#formatCellValue-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator-):

> Returns the formatted value of a cell as a String regardless of the
>   cell type.